# Javascripts - Auto refresh with random number

Tags: random, numbers, refresh

I want to generate random number for refresh page

How to set `math.random` between 20 sec until 50 sec?

My Javascript code looks like this:

```
var number = Math.random() * 50;
var sec = number - (number % 1) + 20;
var url = "http://example.org";

if (sec == 20 || sec == 30 || sec == 40 || sec == 50)

{
    setTimeout(function() { window.location = url } , sec  * 1000 );
}
```

Comment: What did you mean with `(1 == 1)`?

Comment: Btw you can reduce the length of th if query. Using `if ((sec % 10) == 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235156/adding-next-random-previous-buttons-to-this-random-image-script/18318176#18318176) a suggest following statement:

```
var sec = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 20) + 20);
```

I tested it with following script:

```
<script>
a = 20;
b = 50;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a) + a));
}
</script>
```

and it has never generated a number lower than 20 and higher than 50.